# Need to change video src every single day with JavaScript using the Date() function

Tags: javascript

I have a project that has HTML5 video slider and I added it to an array so that I can loop through it `var videoSources = ["video/kid.mp4", "video/hands.mp4", "video/video5.mp4", "video/action.mp4"];`

I want to change the first video to second if the user visits again after a day example if I visit on 1st on the month the first video needs to play and next on 2nd until 4th(number of videos is fixed)then play 1st video in 5th and so on.I am trying to do that with JavaScript Data() function to check the client system date and play the corresponding video can anyone help me to write a better Code instead of writing all day condition line

```
 if(date===1){play 1st},
 if(date===2){play 2nd},
 if(date===3){play 3rd},
 if(date===4){play 4th},
 if(date===5){play 1st}
 ect...
```

Comment: Learn about the modulus operator.

Comment: If you're checking a single variable for multiple values you should use a switch statement.

Comment: I know modulus (4%2=0,10%3=1 right?)I am trying to create a relation between dates to write minimal conditions.If you can help me that save my day

Answer (score 1):

Modulus (`%`) divides two numbers and gives you the remainder. It is often used to constrain a number to within a range because the result of `x % y` will always be between `0` and `y - 1` inclusive.

```
let videoSources = [
  "video/kid.mp4", 
  "video/hands.mp4", 
  "video/video5.mp4", 
  "video/action.mp4"
];
// subtract 1 because the result of getDate() is not 0 indexed but the array is
let todaysDate = new Date().getDate() - 1;
let videoIndex = todaysDate % videoSources.length;
let videoToPlay = videoSources[videoIndex]
```

Walking through how calculating videoIndex works, if you mod todays date by the length of the array you will get a number between `0` and the length of the array minus one, in this case